# How to measure uncertainty in binary data?

Tags: clustering, binary-data, uncertainty

I want to clusterize binary data, so each object is vector of 50 binary values. For real number I can measure standard deviation in each cluster, or something like that. What can I use for binary data? I plan to use it to determine which number of clusters is optimal.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do these binary values represent? What can be assumed about the process that generates them? What do you expect to achieve by clustering them? Why exactly 50 values per 'object'? How many data do you have? How many clusters can you expect? Etc.

Comment: We can have variance for binary data but as already mentioned the variance itself is of little use. What we want/use for clustering is the *covariance*.